# Dynamically adjust Y axis min/max based on ajax update and data points in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Currently, my graphs are created and then I have the following ajax call that creates the plotLines on the graph:

```
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/limits",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (limits) {
                    console.log(limits);
                    graph1.yAxis[0].update({
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: limits[7].max,
                            color: 'orange',
                            dashStyle: 'dash',
                            width: 2,
                            label: {
                                text: 'USL'
                            }
                        }, {
                            value: limits[7].min,
                            color: 'orange',
                            dashStyle: 'dash',
                            width: 2,
                            label: {
                                text: 'LSL'
                            }
                        }]
                    });
```

The problem is that for some graphs the plotLines are out of Highcharts determined y-axis range (created from the data) so the plotLines do not show on the graphs.

I know I could do this to fix that problem:

```
             $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/limits",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (limits) {
                        console.log(limits);
                        graph1.yAxis[0].update({
                            min: limits[7].min,
                            max: limits[7].max,
                            plotLines: [{
                                value: limits[7].max,
                                color: 'orange',
                                dashStyle: 'dash',
                                width: 2,
                                label: {
                                    text: 'USL'
                                }
                            }, {
                                value: limits[7].min,
                                color: 'orange',
                                dashStyle: 'dash',
                                width: 2,
                                label: {
                                    text: 'LSL'
                                }
                            }]
                        });
```

However.. if I was to do that solution then if the graph has points outside of the plotLines, then those points would not be shown.

I figure I could do something like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var min = yAxis[0].min;
      var max = yAxis[0].max;
      if (limits[7].max > max) {
        yAxis[0].setExtremes(null, (limits[7].max);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate that type of logic for both the max and min plotLines into the update function.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the plot line value to the actual axis extremes and change min and max properties if necessary. For example:

```
yAxis.update({
  min: yAxis.min > limits.min ? limits.min : null,
  max: yAxis.max < limits.max ? limits.max : null,
  plotLines: [{
    value: limits.max,
    width: 2,
    color: 'orange'
  }, {
    value: limits.min,
    width: 2,
    color: 'blue'
  }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4989/